Push notifications from app when new record is added in firebase realtime database
My question is that how can I add the notifications in my app when new record is added in the firebase realtime database. I am using java for backend. I've checked the documentation but was not able to find any way.
I thought of trying FCM but I don't know how to use it. If anything which can help or guide me to do this stuff please let me know. Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

StackOverflow is meant to be used for programming problems not for providing solutions to implementing a sending notifications mechanism. So I recommend you give a try using the official documentation, and ask another question if something in your code doesn't work the way you expect.

The Firebase documentation has an example of precisely what you're asking here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens
